# REGEX filter with Pandas (any numeric combination followed by 'plus' sign)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe called `df` with the following 3 columns: `id`, `creation_date` and `email`.

I want to return all rows where the **`email`** column contains any strictly numeric combination (must be strictly numbers) followed by a 'plus' sign and then followed by anything.

For example:
- `1345677+@gmail.com`, `2345678+556@gmail.com` will meet my criteria.
- `Testing+22@gmail.com` and `test223+22@gmail.com` will not, because they contain non-numeric characters before the 'plus' sign.

I know `df.email.str.contains('\+')` won't work because it will return everything that contains a 'plus' sign. I had tried `df.filter(['email'], regex=r'([^0-9])' % '\+', axis=0)` but it threw an error message that read `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Also, I find [regex101](https://regex101.com/) helpful whenever I'm doing regex things.

Comment: Thank you, @McClAnalytics. I found the link quite useful too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `contains`, but [`match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) should be sufficient:

```
# example data
data = ["1345677+@gmail.com", "2345678+556@gmail.com", 
        "Testing+22@gmail.com", "test223+22@gmail.com"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["email"])

df
                   email
0     1345677+@gmail.com
1  2345678+556@gmail.com
2   Testing+22@gmail.com
3   test223+22@gmail.com
```

Now use `match`:

```
df.email.str.match("\d+\+.*")

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: email, dtype: bool
```

Note the difference between `contains` and `match`, from the docs:

> **contains**
>   analogous, but less strict, relying on re.search instead of re.match

Comment: Thank you, @andrew_reece. This solved my problem. May I ask what is the purpose of the period '.' in front of '*'? I had tried removing the '.' from the parenthesis and the result picked up emails like '44watt+btc@gmail.com' and '7ronin+shit@gmail.com' as True, but they should be flagged as False because they don't match my criteria. So I wasn't sure what is the magic behind the period '.'

Comment: The `.` is a called a _wildcard_ in regex, it matches any character.  The `*` that follows it indicates that the wildcard can occur any number of times (including zero times).  Basically, `.*` is another way of saying "match everything", which fits your criteria.  But if you take away the`.`, then you have `\d+\+*`, which now means "match a digit at least once and then match `+` any number of times.  Since `44watt+btc` matches a digit at least once and then matches `+` any number of times immediately afterward (in this case, zero times - as we get a `w` instead) - you get a match.

Comment: This is super helpful explanation, @andrew_reece! Thank you! Now I understand how and when to use the '.' and '*' notations :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.email.str.contains('^\d+\+\@')
```

In breaking down the regular expression:

`^` ensures that we are starting at the beginning of the email string

`\d+` captures only digit (numeric) character 1 to many times

`\+` escapes the plus sign to ensure a match

`\@` escapes the @ and ensures that the plus sign previously matched occurs at the end of the email just prior to the @

Comment: Thanks, @McCIAnalytics. I also added '*' to the end of the parenthesis so the final version becomes '^\d+\+\@*'. Without the '*', regex would treat '@' as the last character in the email.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `^\d+\+\d*@\S+`

[image]

**Details**:

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`\+` matches the character + literally

`\d*` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]), `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times

`@` matches the character @

`\S+` matches any non-whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zz7k3P/1)

Answer (score 0):

Since your combination is followed by `+` which might be followed by digits you can try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\d+\+?)+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\d+\+?)+` will match your pattern of ``` digit``+ ```.
- `[a-z]+\.[a-z]+` will match remaining part.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cAY186/2/)**